# how to duplicate and modified data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to duplicated some data based on condition and then data duplicated must be edit.

Example of my `df1`

```
df1 <- data.frame(value = c("0","0","50","0","25","67"),
                  Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","alpha","beta","charli"),
                  Position = c("A","A","A","B","B","A"))
```

The condition I want to duplicated is `if value > 0` and `Rank = A`.
My second `df` is

```
df2 <- data.frame(value = c("0","0","50","50","0","25","67","67"),
                  Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","charli","alpha","beta","charli","charli"),
                  Position = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","A","A"))
```

And then i want to modified the two of data (duplicate and duplicated) like this. My final `df` is

```
df <- data.frame(value = c("0","0","0","50","0","25","0","67"),
                 Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","charli","alpha","beta","charli","charli"),
                 Position = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","B"))
```

1 data values will be 0 and if value is not 0, the position is B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R you can duplicate the rows and replace the values according to your instructions.

```
# condition
pos <- df1$value > 0 & df1$Position == "A"

# duplicate rows
new_rows <- rep(1:nrow(df1), pos+1)
df <- df1[new_rows,]

# replace value 0 for first duplicate
df[cumsum(pos+1)[pos]-1, "value"] <- "0"
# replace Position B for second duplicate
df[cumsum(pos+1)[pos], "Position"] <- "B"

df
#>     value   Name Position
#> 1       0  alpha        A
#> 2       0   beta        A
#> 3       0 charli        A
#> 3.1    50 charli        B
#> 4       0  alpha        B
#> 5      25   beta        B
#> 6       0 charli        A
#> 6.1    67 charli        B
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try this (I am not proficient in `dplyr`, and I believe the code below can be further improved)

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(rid = row_number()) %>%
    filter(!(value > 0 & Position == "A")) %>%
    bind_rows(df1 %>%
        mutate(rid = row_number()) %>%
        slice(rep(which(value > 0 & Position == "A"), each = 2)) %>%
        mutate(
            value = replace(value, rowid(value) %% 2 == 1, 0),
            Position = replace(Position, rowid(Position) %% 2 == 0, "B")
        )) %>%
    arrange(rid) %>%
    select(-rid)
```

which gives

```
  value   Name Position
1     0  alpha        A
2     0   beta        A
3     0 charli        A
4    50 charli        B
5     0  alpha        B
6    25   beta        B
7     0 charli        A
8    67 charli        B
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df1 <- tibble(value = c("0","0","50","0","25","67"),
              Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","alpha","beta","charli"),
              Position = c("A","A","A","B","B","A")) 

df2 <- tibble(value = c("0","0","50","50","0","25","67","67"),
              Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","charli","alpha","beta","charli","charli"),
              Position = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","A","A"))

df <- tibble(value = c("0","0","0","50","0","25","0","67"),
             Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","charli","alpha","beta","charli","charli"),
             Position = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","B"))

# Create df using code and store in df_alt
df_alt <-
  df1 |> 
  union_all(
    # Add duplicates
    df1 |> 
      filter(value > 0, Position == "A") |> 
      mutate(value = "0")) |>
  # Change Position
  mutate(Position = if_else(value != "0", "B", Position)) 

# Check that df_alt and df are identical (apart from row order)
df_alt |>
  anti_join(df)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(value, Name, Position)`
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # ℹ 3 variables: value <chr>, Name <chr>, Position <chr>

df |>
  anti_join(df_alt)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(value, Name, Position)`
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # ℹ 3 variables: value <chr>, Name <chr>, Position <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>